# How to abbreviate MySQL queries in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page that needs to make six nearly identical queries with the only difference between them being the value of "category":

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE category="CATEGORY1";
```

Instead of writing out six different $query variables ($query1, $query2, etc.) for each different category, I'd like to abbreviate so I can pass in category as a variable each time I instantiate $query, like so:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE category='$cat'";
$results= mysql_query($query,'CATEGORY1');
```

There must be some way to do this, but I simply can't find the syntax anywhere for passing a variable to a MySQL query in this way (I checked php.net, this site, various other php resources on Google). Can anyone help me out?

Much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This is the primeval use case for prepared statements. Which is really simple if you use `?` placeholders and just pass parameters as list to `->execute()`.

Comment: "primeval"? That can't be right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sprintf` for that:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE category='%s'";
$results= mysql_query(sprintf($query,'CATEGORY1'));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php)

```
$categories = array(
    'CATEGORY1',
    'CATEGORY2',
    'CATEGORY3',
    'CATEGORY4',
    'CATEGORY5',
    'CATEGORY6'
);

$db = new PDO(...);
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE category = :category');
$stmt->bindParam('category', $category);
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $stmt->execute();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        // do stuff with $row
    }
}
```

Comment: While it's nice this is parameterized, isn't it still executing a statement per category?

Comment: @OMGPonies Yes, but that statement is only prepared / compiled once. In the OP, each statement would be compiled separately.

Comment: Never do in six queries, what you can in one.

Comment: @OMGPonies I agree and a `SELECT` query is hardly the best example to use in this case. In fact, parameter binding in a loop is usually best applied to `INSERT` / `UPDATE` queries.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a single variable in SQL to represent a comma separated list, like I'd use for situations like these as values for an IN clause.  You need to use dynamic SQL, which means constructing the query as a string before submitting it to the database.

```
$array = array('category1', 'category2', 'category3');
$comma_separated = implode("','", $array);

$query = "SELECT * 
            FROM table_name 
           WHERE category IN ('$comma_separated')";

$results = mysql_query($query);
```

An alternative would be to use [MySQL's Prepared Statement syntax](http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2005/11/mysql-5-prepared-statement-syntax-and.html), which is MySQL's dynamic SQL syntax...

Comment: Don't forget the start and end quotes ;-)